# invalid_grant of OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm working on writing fully customized ASP.NET Identity for my WebAPi.

I have rewritten my own derived OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider in this way:

```
 public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
 {
     context.Validated();
     return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
 }

 public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
 {
     // Check User availability ...
     //ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

     // if i couldn't found user in my DataBase ... 
     //if (user == null)
     //{
     //context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
     //    return;
     //}

     context.Validated();
 }
}
```

`GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` just returns an `invalid_grant` error for each calls. i want to handle it but, i don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ValidateClientAuthentication** is where you would do your authentication checks and this is where you throw errors if anything doesn't match.

move your code there and do the checks before you call context.Validated(). You only call the Validate method once you make sure everything is validated correctly.

here is an example of such an implementation I did a while back:

```
public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            string clientId;
            string clientSecret;

            //first try to get the client details from the Authorization Basic header
            if (!context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
            {
                //no details in the Authorization Header so try to find matching post values
                context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret);
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientId) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientSecret))
            {
                context.SetError("client_not_authorized", "invalid client details");
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }

            var dataLayer = new RepoManager(new DataLayerDapper()).DataLayer;
            var audienceDto = dataLayer.GetAudience(clientId);

            if (audienceDto == null || !clientSecret.Equals(audienceDto.Secret))
            {
                context.SetError("unauthorized_client", "unauthorized client");
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }

            context.Validated();
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
```

Notice how the checks happen in order and certain errors are raised with some appropriate errors.

This code takes a client id and client secret from an authorization header but you can easily drop all that and replace it with your own checks and database calls.

The important part is that this is where you deal with stuff like this and this is where you set the errors so your clients know what's going on.

**GrantResourceOwnerCredentials** this is where you get once the call is properly authenticated, at which point you can start creating tokens, adding claims and creating the authentication ticket. This method does not get hit if the previous one fails to authenticate the request.

Here is a working example:

```
public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("JWT");                                            
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("clientID", context.ClientId));

            var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {
                         "audience", context.ClientId 
                    }                    
                });

            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props); 
            context.Validated(ticket);
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
```

Now, if you get an invalid grant error that usually happens because you either didn't set up the **grant_type** in your initial call or you set up the wrong value.

in my case I had to setup this:

"grant_type", "password"